# Starting mathematics reading for quants

Tags: reference-request

What book should I start with in order to learn about the mathematics behind financial (derivatives I think!) trading that would be used in HF's & IB's (Not sure whether there would be a difference).

I have a strong background in mathematics particularly with regard to measure theory, probability theory and stochastic calculus having studied Rana, Kai-Lee Chung & Oksendals famous texts on these subjects. I also have a strong knowledge of partial differential equations. (Not sure what other areas of mathematics would be useful?)

I am looking for the most concise and quickest way to teach myself about the core mathematics and ideas behind quantative finance.

Comment: ...or lecture notes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider:

1. Wilmott, P., Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance 3 Volume Set
2. Hull, J. C., Options, Futures and Other Derivatives
3. Baxter, M. & Rennie, A., Financial Calculus: An Introduction to Derivative Pricing
4. McNeil, A. et al, Quantitative Risk Management: Concepts, Techniques and Tools
5. Brigo, D. & Mercurio, F., Interest Rate Models - Theory and Practice

for $\mathbb{Q}$-type introductory reading. On the $\mathbb{P}$-side, it depends what you're looking for - volatility trading, interest rates, $\Delta1$, cash products, risk management, market models, numerical techniques, data-driven techniques etc.

Comment: What about equity derivatives? Interest rate products?

Comment: For interest rates... Rebonato has two books - Modern Pricing of Interest-Rate Derivatives and Interest-Rate Option Models. I would also look at Pelsser's Efficient Methods for Valuing Interest Rate and James & Webber's Interest Rate Modelling.

Comment: Equity options are probably the most thoroughly-covered among financial engineering texts so I think the 4 books I've recommended cover most of the introductory reading that you need. In addition to that, perhaps you could take a look at Rebonato's Volatility and Correlation, and Sinclair's two books.

Comment: how about credit trading?

Comment: Im really not sure what I would like most, so may be interested.

Comment: @athos / 1234 - Unfortunately, I hadn't come from a credit trading background. However, Tuckman and Serrat's book discusses credit default swaps, credit risk of corporate bonds and spreads and Veronesi's book briefly touches on collateralized mortgage obligations.
Mike - My colleague asks me to say hi. (:

Comment: Mike? @1234 -- your acquaintance?

Comment: Not my acquaintance. Nor do I have any colleagues.

Comment: Not you two, silly. :)

Comment: @madilyn ah got it. Hi to Mike :)

Answer (score 5):

Introductory:
"Introduction to the Mathematics of Financial Derivatives"; Salih Neftci

More mathematical:
"Stochastic Calculus for Finance I and II"; Steven Shreve

Comment: Is stochastic calculus for finance I really worth reading? Looks pretty discrete

Comment: Stoch Calc I can be useful. Some interesting foundational material. Yes its largely discrete. But it could be skipped if you are already familiar with Oksendal et al.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to start with one of the coursera course, *Mathematical Methods for Quantitative Finance*. It's an introductory course on mathematical concepts that can be applied in finance.

**Books:**
1) A Primer for Mathematics of Financial Engineering.
2) Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance.

Also, check out this article on Quantnet: [Master Reading list for Financial Engineering Students](https://www.quantnet.com/threads/master-reading-list-for-quants-mfe-financial-engineering-students.535/)

I hope this helps you.